# How to hide footnote separator in beamer animated slides?

Tags: beamer, footnotes, animations

I have a slide that have two images that are uncovered in parts. One of the figure has a caption and a footnote associated with the caption. I am able to uncover the footnote at the right instant but the footnote separator appears on all the slides as shown below. A MWE is given below:

```
\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Title}
        \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
                \begin{figure}
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                        \only<1>
                            {
                            \node [inner sep=0pt,opacity=0.2]
                                {
                                \includegraphics[height=4cm,keepaspectratio,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}
                                };                      
                            }
                        \only<2->
                            {
                            \node [inner sep=0pt]
                                {
                                \includegraphics[height=4cm,keepaspectratio,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}
                                };              
                            }
                    \end{tikzpicture}
                    \onslide<2->
                        {       
                        \caption{Caption 1\footnotemark}
                        }
                \end{figure}
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
                \begin{figure}
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                        \only<1-2>
                            {
                            \node [inner sep=0pt,opacity=0.2]
                                {
                                \includegraphics[height=4cm,keepaspectratio,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-b}
                                };
                            }
                        \only<3->
                            {
                            \node [inner sep=0pt]
                                {
                                \includegraphics[height=4cm,keepaspectratio,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-b}
                                };
                            }
                    \end{tikzpicture} 
                    \onslide<3->
                        {
                        \caption{Caption 2}
                        }
                \end{figure}
            \end{column}            
        \end{columns}
            \footnotetext<2->{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How to hide the footnote separator for the first part of the slide?

**Update**

I do not want to use \only as it causes the position of the images to shift based on the size of the footnote text.

**Slides**

[image: Slide a]
[image: Slide b]
[image: Slide c]

Answer (score 1):

Just use `\only`.

```
\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Title}
        \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
                \begin{figure}
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                        \only<1>
                            {
                            \node [inner sep=0pt,opacity=0.2]
                                {
                                \includegraphics[height=4cm,keepaspectratio,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}
                                };                      
                            }
                        \only<2->
                            {
                            \node [inner sep=0pt]
                                {
                                \includegraphics[height=4cm,keepaspectratio,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}
                                };              
                            }
                    \end{tikzpicture}
                    \onslide<2->
                        {       
                        \caption{Caption 1\footnotemark}
                        }
                \end{figure}
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
                \begin{figure}
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                        \only<1-2>
                            {
                            \node [inner sep=0pt,opacity=0.2]
                                {
                                \includegraphics[height=4cm,keepaspectratio,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-b}
                                };
                            }
                        \only<3->
                            {
                            \node [inner sep=0pt]
                                {
                                \includegraphics[height=4cm,keepaspectratio,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-b}
                                };
                            }
                    \end{tikzpicture} 
                    \onslide<3->
                        {
                        \caption{Caption 2}
                        }
                \end{figure}
            \end{column}            
        \end{columns}
            \only<2->{
            \footnotetext{Lorem ipsum}}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention that \only causes the images to shift position and I do not want to use it.

Comment: @nxkryptor I see. You do not want to get rid of the footnote rule altogether but only on slide 1, nor just use `\begin{frame}[t]`, right?

Comment: Yes, footnote rule should be visible on all slides except slide 1 and I do not want to use \begin{frame}[t].